# JTable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of undefined

Tags: php, jquery, jtable

Will you please help me wht this error occur. **JTable Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of undefined**

**Ajax work i got a  valid response but it doesnt fetch and shows in the table**

Will you please help me. In other hand if i script i put it on the sepearate file how can i call this?

```
<div id="church_list" style="width: 600px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jTable
        $('#church_list').jtable({
            title: 'Church List',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'church_name ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: server_path+'/superadmin/?a=listChurch'
            },
            fields: {
                church_name: {
                    title: 'Church Name',
                    width: '30%'
                },
                church_city: {
                    title: 'Church City',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                church_state: {
                    title: 'Church State',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                payment_type: {
                    title: 'Payment Type',
                    width: '20%'
                },
                training_cost: {
                    title: 'Training Cost',
                    width: '20%'
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#church_list').jtable('load');

    });

</script>
```

Comment: So there's an internal error in some random plugin, and you want us to figure it out ?

Comment: {"Result":"OK","TotalRecordCount":50,"Records":[{"church_name":"Test","church_city":"Test","church_state":"TEST","payment_type":"Test","training_cost":"10.00"}]}

Comment: Yes i dont know why it occurss??

Comment: please provide whole ajax page in your question.... @user2617449

Answer (score 0):

1) Likely you are using an older version of jquery - especially if you are using the code that comes with the downloads.  I had something similar out of the box and moved to a newer version and the problem went away with no other changes.

https://github.com/hikalkan/jtable/issues/953

2) You do not have an ID/primary key - I've been able to add that without making any jquery changes and the table will render.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this problem was solved or not but I remind this:

listAction is an object.

change the code like this:

```
listAction:{
    method: *your URL*
}
```